# Does one need a understanding in Convolutional Neural Networks before learning about Quantum Convolutional Neural Networks

Tags: neural-network, convolutional-neural-network

I have a degree in Physcis and want to learn about Quantum Convolutional Neural Networks.

Is it recommeneded that i known about Convolutional Neural Networks before learning about Quantum Convolutional Neural Networks.

Comment: Well... yes, it is recommended, but clearly CNN are nothing compared to quantum computers. You take more time writing this question than learning the basics for CNNs.